# Adding an "Open In..." menu

Tags: iphone, ios

My iOS app handles PDF files and I want to be able to open my file in another application so I want to add the "Open In..." menu (Seen [here](http://blog.vembu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/SyncBlaze_OpenIn_Feature.png)). How could I do this?

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Your app should show the list or appear in the list?

Comment: @Wain No my app should not. I just want to be able to see a list of apps that will open my file

Comment: See the docs for `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu is called UIDocumentInteractionController. Docs are here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html

You'll want it as a property (otherwise, it will get released before you even get to present it)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController;
```

To display it:

```
self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPDFPath]];

[self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.actionButton animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

To offer the PDF to other apps, look at using `UIActivityViewController` or `UIDocumentInteractionController` with a URL which links to the PDF file.

To allow other apps to pass PDF files to your app you need to configure it as a viewer / editor of PDF files in the info.plist (`CFBundleDocumentTypes`) and handle the supplied information when the app is launched.

Comment: This answers a different question. The OP wants their app to appear in the "Open In" menu of other apps for PDF files.

Comment: @rmaddy, reading again I can see the ambiguity.

Comment: Yeah, after another reading I'm now not so sure which way they want the file to go.

Comment: @rmaddy I want the file to from my app to another app (ex. iBooks)